# Trigger error in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I want to insert informations from carti into domeniu but i get an error message.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_UpdateItemDetails ON carti
FOR INSERT AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO 
domeniu
(
    cod_d,
    materia,
    result
)
SELECT 
    id
    domeniu
    nr_exemplare
FROM 
   carti
END
```

> The error message: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'ON result FOR INSERT AS BEGIN INSERT INTO domeniu
>   ( ' at line 1

Comment: Post the error message as well.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is `FOR INSERT AS`. It should `BEFORE INSERT AS`. Check  [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html) for `CREATE TRIGGER` syntax. Looks like you mixed up `SQL Serer` syntax. `For Trigger` is MSSQL syntax.

```
CREATE
    [DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]
    TRIGGER trigger_name
    trigger_time trigger_event
    ON tbl_name FOR EACH ROW
    [trigger_order]
    trigger_body

trigger_time: { BEFORE | AFTER }

trigger_event: { INSERT | UPDATE | DELETE }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should name the triggers using the following naming convention:

```
(BEFORE | AFTER)_tableName_(INSERT| UPDATE | DELETE)
```

for example `after_tableName_insert`

Refer below tutorial for creating triggers.
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-trigger-implementation.aspx